# The Meaning of "Sat at The Head of The Party"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

What's the meaning of *sat at the head of the party*

> Gandalf **sat at the head of the party** with the thirteen dwarves all round: and Bilbo sat on a stool at the fireside, nibbling at a biscuit (his appetite was quite taken away), and trying to look as if this was all perfectly ordinary and not in the least an adventure. The dwarves ate and ate, and talked and talked, and time got on. At last they pushed their chairs back, and Bilbo made a move to collect the plates and glasses.
>
> The Hobbit, J.R.R. Tolkien

"Head of the party" is not an idiom according to my research, unless *party* refers to a [*political party*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_party). It's probably a metaphor.

Answer (score 11):

A party can be a group of people assembled for some reason. To sit at the head of something, e.g. a table, is to sit at one end so that everyone can see and hear you. It implies seniority, leadership, or host status.

In this diagram, person A sits at the head of the table, and person B at the foot of the table.

[image]

Comment: Clear as crystal. Thank you!

Comment: Although it's debatable which end of the table is the head and which is the foot.  I'd guess that the head is the end closer to the kitchen?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The head is the end of the table which gets served first. Then those on either side are served, working down the table, and those near the foot get served last.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's often made clear simply by the status of the various people - the higher status will be nearer the head.  Of course, this is only relevant in those cases where people care about status.

Comment: @PrimeMover Though if you've got enough serving staff, they can serve both ends at once and work their way down either side...  It was not unusual for example in certain times for the Lord and Lady of the estate to sit at opposite ends, both of them having higher status than any of their guests.  Although sometimes they'd sit together in the middle of the table instead, and the ends weren't anything special.  I'm sure there's whole books of etiquette on the various possible seating arrangements...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - check out the meaning of 'below the salt'.

Comment: Typically, the chair at the head of the table is larger and more ornate than all the others: more like a throne. Where a couple are hosts, the female sits at the foot to ensure conversation is maintained evenly, and naturally has an intermediate style of chair. (Note: I am describing the 18th/19th century era, with no intention to offend.)